# \cite command using cite package in X column of tabularx cannot be centered

Tags: pdftex, natbib, tabularx, cite-package

In the following example, using `natbib` package can be centered in the `X` column, but `cite` package can't. I want to know why?

```latex
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx}
% \usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}
\cite{ref1,ref2,ref3,ref4,ref5,ref6,ref7,ref8,ref9,ref10,ref11,ref12,ref13,ref14,ref15,ref16,ref17,ref18,ref19,ref20,ref21,ref22,ref23}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|Y|Y|Y|c|}
\hline
& [45] & \cite{ref1} & \cite{ref12} & \cite{ref23} \\
\hline
XXXXX & Y & Y & N & Y \\
XXXXX & Y & Y & N & Y \\
XXXXX & Y & Y & N & Y \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{reference}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

There is `reference.bib` for testing.

```latex
@article{ref1, author = {Murad A. Abusubaih and Sundous Khamayseh}, title = {Performance of Machine Learning-Based Techniques for Spectrum Sensing in Mobile Cognitive Radio Networks}, journal = {{IEEE} Access}, volume = {10}, pages = {1410--1418}, year = {2022} }
@article{ref2, author = {Murad A. Abusubaih and Sundous Khamayseh}, title = {Performance of Machine Learning-Based Techniques for Spectrum Sensing in Mobile Cognitive Radio Networks}, journal = {{IEEE} Access}, volume = {10}, pages = {1410--1418}, year = {2022} }
@article{ref3, author = {Murad A. Abusubaih and Sundous Khamayseh}, title = {Performance of Machine Learning-Based Techniques for Spectrum Sensing in Mobile Cognitive Radio Networks}, journal = {{IEEE} Access}, volume = {10}, pages = {1410--1418}, year = {2022} }
@article{ref4, author = {Murad A. Abusubaih and Sundous Khamayseh}, title = {Performance of Machine Learning-Based Techniques for Spectrum Sensing in Mobile Cognitive Radio Networks}, journal = {{IEEE} Access}, volume = {10}, pages = {1410--1418}, year = {2022} }
@article{ref5, author = {Murad A. Abusubaih and Sundous Khamayseh}, title = {Performance of Machine Learning-Based Techniques for Spectrum Sensing in Mobile Cognitive Radio Networks}, journal = {{IEEE} Access}, volume = {10}, pages = {1410--1418}, year = {2022} }
@article{ref6, author = {Murad A. Abusubaih and Sundous Khamayseh}, title = {Performance of Machine Learning-Based Techniques for Spectrum Sensing in Mobile Cognitive Radio Networks}, journal = {{IEEE} Access}, volume = {10}, pages = {1410--1418}, year = {2022} }
@article{ref7, author = {Murad A. Abusubaih and Sundous Khamayseh}, title = {Performance of Machine Learning-Based Techniques for Spectrum Sensing in Mobile Cognitive Radio Networks}, journal = {{IEEE} Access}, volume = {10}, pages = {1410--1418}, year = {2022} }
@article{ref8, author = {Murad A. Abusubaih and Sundous Khamayseh}, title = {Performance of Machine Learning-Based Techniques for Spectrum Sensing in Mobile Cognitive Radio Networks}, journal = {{IEEE} Access}, volume = {10}, pages = {1410--1418}, year = {2022} }
@article{ref9, author = {Murad A. Abusubaih and Sundous Khamayseh}, title = {Performance of Machine Learning-Based Techniques for Spectrum Sensing in Mobile Cognitive Radio Networks}, journal = {{IEEE} Access}, volume = {10}, pages = {1410--1418}, year = {2022} }
@article{ref10, author = {Murad A. Abusubaih and Sundous Khamayseh}, title = {Performance of Machine Learning-Based Techniques for Spectrum Sensing in Mobile Cognitive Radio Networks}, journal = {{IEEE} Access}, volume = {10}, pages = {1410--1418}, year = {2022} }
@article{ref11, author = {Murad A. Abusubaih and Sundous Khamayseh}, title = {Performance of Machine Learning-Based Techniques for Spectrum Sensing in Mobile Cognitive Radio Networks}, journal = {{IEEE} Access}, volume = {10}, pages = {1410--1418}, year = {2022} }
@article{ref12, author = {Murad A. Abusubaih and Sundous Khamayseh}, title = {Performance of Machine Learning-Based Techniques for Spectrum Sensing in Mobile Cognitive Radio Networks}, journal = {{IEEE} Access}, volume = {10}, pages = {1410--1418}, year = {2022} }
@article{ref13, author = {Murad A. Abusubaih and Sundous Khamayseh}, title = {Performance of Machine Learning-Based Techniques for Spectrum Sensing in Mobile Cognitive Radio Networks}, journal = {{IEEE} Access}, volume = {10}, pages = {1410--1418}, year = {2022} }
@article{ref14, author = {Murad A. Abusubaih and Sundous Khamayseh}, title = {Performance of Machine Learning-Based Techniques for Spectrum Sensing in Mobile Cognitive Radio Networks}, journal = {{IEEE} Access}, volume = {10}, pages = {1410--1418}, year = {2022} }
@article{ref15, author = {Murad A. Abusubaih and Sundous Khamayseh}, title = {Performance of Machine Learning-Based Techniques for Spectrum Sensing in Mobile Cognitive Radio Networks}, journal = {{IEEE} Access}, volume = {10}, pages = {1410--1418}, year = {2022} }
@article{ref16, author = {Murad A. Abusubaih and Sundous Khamayseh}, title = {Performance of Machine Learning-Based Techniques for Spectrum Sensing in Mobile Cognitive Radio Networks}, journal = {{IEEE} Access}, volume = {10}, pages = {1410--1418}, year = {2022} }
@article{ref17, author = {Murad A. Abusubaih and Sundous Khamayseh}, title = {Performance of Machine Learning-Based Techniques for Spectrum Sensing in Mobile Cognitive Radio Networks}, journal = {{IEEE} Access}, volume = {10}, pages = {1410--1418}, year = {2022} }
@article{ref18, author = {Murad A. Abusubaih and Sundous Khamayseh}, title = {Performance of Machine Learning-Based Techniques for Spectrum Sensing in Mobile Cognitive Radio Networks}, journal = {{IEEE} Access}, volume = {10}, pages = {1410--1418}, year = {2022} }
@article{ref19, author = {Murad A. Abusubaih and Sundous Khamayseh}, title = {Performance of Machine Learning-Based Techniques for Spectrum Sensing in Mobile Cognitive Radio Networks}, journal = {{IEEE} Access}, volume = {10}, pages = {1410--1418}, year = {2022} }
@article{ref20, author = {Murad A. Abusubaih and Sundous Khamayseh}, title = {Performance of Machine Learning-Based Techniques for Spectrum Sensing in Mobile Cognitive Radio Networks}, journal = {{IEEE} Access}, volume = {10}, pages = {1410--1418}, year = {2022} }
@article{ref21, author = {Murad A. Abusubaih and Sundous Khamayseh}, title = {Performance of Machine Learning-Based Techniques for Spectrum Sensing in Mobile Cognitive Radio Networks}, journal = {{IEEE} Access}, volume = {10}, pages = {1410--1418}, year = {2022} }
@article{ref22, author = {Murad A. Abusubaih and Sundous Khamayseh}, title = {Performance of Machine Learning-Based Techniques for Spectrum Sensing in Mobile Cognitive Radio Networks}, journal = {{IEEE} Access}, volume = {10}, pages = {1410--1418}, year = {2022} }
@article{ref23, author = {Murad A. Abusubaih and Sundous Khamayseh}, title = {Performance of Machine Learning-Based Techniques for Spectrum Sensing in Mobile Cognitive Radio Networks}, journal = {{IEEE} Access}, volume = {10}, pages = {1410--1418}, year = {2022} }
```

In addition, what are the advantages and disadvantages of `natbib` package and `cite` package?  I refer to the example in IEEE `bare_adv.tex`, which is why I use `cite` package.

Comment: Try using `\fbox{\cite{...}}` if the padding inside this box is not symmetrical then cite is adding space. You might want to read the manual for the cite package. Btw why are you using the cite package in the first place?

Comment: @daleif In the sample file `bare_adv.tex` of IEEE paper template, the `cite` package is given. According to the answer below, just add the `noadjust` parameter is solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is by design and documented in the cite package

```
%  Put a penalty before the citation, and adjust the spacing: if no space
%  already or if there is extra space due to some punctuation, then change
%  to one inter-word space.
```

You can use

```
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
```

to avoid adjusting the space, but then you would get no space added in the first case in the test file below.

A simpler test file would be

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

word\cite{zz}

\fbox{\cite{zz}}

\fbox{\parbox{1cm}{\centering \cite{zz}\\XX}}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem[zz]{zz} Something that got cited.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

It would be perhaps better if the package did not add the space if it is in vertical mode and in vertical mode only add it after a character (or perhaps some other types as well, but just character here)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cite}

\makeatletter
\def\@cite#1#2{%
% old \leavevmode \cite@adjust
  \relax\ifvmode\leavevmode\else
  \ifnum\lastnodetype=0 \cite@adjust\fi\fi
% end of change
  \citeleft{#1\if@tempswa\@safe@activesfalse\citemid{#2}\fi
  \spacefactor\@m % punctuation in note doesn't affect outside
  }\citeright
 \@restore@auxhandle}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

word\cite{zz}

\fbox{\cite{zz}}

\fbox{\parbox{1cm}{\centering \cite{zz}\\XX}}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem[zz]{zz} Something that got cited.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or, you could just load the package with the option `noadjust`. :-)

Comment: @Mico yes but then you would get word[zz] for the first line (but yes I should mention this) thanks

Comment: Thank you very much. I usually add `~` before `\cite`, so I can solve my problem by using option `noadjust`.

Answer (score 5):

To obtain fully centered single numeric-style citation call-outs with the `cite` citation management package, you need to load the package with the `noadjust` option:

```
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
```

That said, I can't think of a good reason for *not* employing the `natbib` package instead:

```
\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, which solved my question. David Carlisle answered earlier, so I adopted his answer.